# length of list contents with lists inside

Tags: python, list, count, items

Is there command to get total count of list items with lists inside?

Example:

```
Names = [['Mark'], ['John', 'Mary'], ['Cindy', 'Tom'], ['Ben']]
print (len(Names))
```

**Output**

```
4
```

But I want total count of list items so that result would be 6. I just started learning python, so go easy on me.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#map) to apply a function to every element of an iterable. Here we apply the `len` function and `sum` the results:

```
Names = [['Mark'], ['John', 'Mary'], ['Cindy', 'Tom'], ['Ben']]
print(sum(map(len, Names)))
# 6
```

This (and all the other answers) works only as long as each element of `Names` is actually a `list`. If one of them is a `str`, it will add the length of the string and if it does not have a length (like `int` or `float`) it will raise a `TypeError`.

Since the functional approach is sometimes frowned upon in modern Python, you can also use a [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) (actually a [generator comprehension](https://djangostars.com/blog/list-comprehensions-and-generator-expressions/)):

```
print(sum(len(x) for x in Names))
# 6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

nameslen = 0

""" There is a list named Names wich contains 4 lists, 0 = ["Mark]
                                                       1 = ['John', 'Mary']
                                                       2 = ['Cindy', 'Tom']
                                                       3 = ['Ben']
"""

Names = [['Mark'], ['John', 'Mary'], ['Cindy', 'Tom'], ['Ben']]

# using print (len(Names)) you will get as result 4, 
# that means list Names contain 4 lists 


for x in range(len(Names)):
    # for each list in Names lists
    # len the list values  
    nameslen += len(Names[x])

print (nameslen)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

```
Names = [['Mark'], ['John', 'Mary'], ['Cindy', 'Tom'], ['Ben']]

no_of_names = 0

for name_list in Names:
    if isinstance(name_list,list):
        no_of_names += len(name_list)
    elif isinstance(name_list,str):
        no_of_names += 1

print(no_of_names)
```

**Output**

```
6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Iterable

names = [['Mark'], ['John', 'Mary'], ['Cindy', 'Tom'], ['Ben']]

count = 0
ignore_types = (str,bytes)

for x in names:
    if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, ignore_types):
        count += len(x)
    else:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

This checks if the item in the list is an iterable object like a list or string. If its a list then count is incremented by the length of the list or by 1 if the item is in the ignore_types